# Final Fantasy XIII cutscene lag

Tags: final-fantasy-13

I just installed FFXIII on my new laptop.  I've never played the PC version until now.

I turned the graphics all the way up using the pre-game window - rendering real-time game-play is no problem.  I'm getting well over 30fps.  However, the cutscenes seem to be lagging and glitching for some reason.

What could be the cause of the cutscene lag - could it be my laptop, if not, is there anything I can do about this?

Specs:

- Intel i7 (2.4 to 3.6GHz)
- 32GB Ram
- 2x GTX 860 (SLI)
- 3x SSD Raid 0

Comment: Can you choose to run the game in dx9 mode? I recall Batman: Arkham City having the same issue, I'd get 60 fps in game, but pre-rendered cutscenes would stutter. Running the game in dx9 mode fixed it.

Comment: The FF13 port is also fairly lousy - check the steam forums for details. They may improve it in days / weeks / months to come, but possibly not.

Answer (score 1):

Either plug in a usb controller or disable all HID-Compliant devices in the device manager.

The issue is that every couple of seconds, the game is testing all HID-compliant devices for a controller.  These tests interrupt smooth video playback.

If you disable the HID-compliant devices keyboard and mouse should still function, but extra features on them (media buttons) may not.